# Seeking US Highway exits shapefile?

Tags: data, united-states

Does anyone know where to download a shapefile containing the locations of US interstate and highway exits?

Comment: This might be better suited on [opendata.se].

Answer (score 1):

I might suggest using OpenStreetMap and the `highway=motorway_junction` tag/value pair.

From [Overpass Turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/#), use the wizard to build and run a query using that combination, and you'll find you get a decent result set:

[image]

You can either export that result to GeoJSON (or other formats), or use the query in QGIS to download the data directly to your desktop.

Comment: That should be highway = motorway_junction

Answer (score 0):

One source might be the census:
https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles/index.php?year=2017&layergroup=Roads

or FHWA:
https://www.gis.fhwa.dot.gov/gisData.asp